# Eigenstate of a Hamiltonain diagonalized using a paraunitary matrx

Tags: hamiltonian, eigenvalue, bosons, matrix-elements

I have a question regarding the definition of energy eigenstates of Hamiltonian that can be diagonalized using paraunitary matrices.

From quantum mechanics, energy eigenstates are defined by,
$$
\textbf{H}\left|\psi_{j}\right\rangle =E_j\left|\psi_{j}\right\rangle 
$$
where $\textbf{H}$ is the Hamiltonian, $E_j$ is the j$^{th}$ energy level and $\left|\psi_{j}\left(\textbf{k}\right)\right\rangle$ is the j$^{th}$ eigenstate. In matrix representation, the Hamiltonian can be diagonalized using the unitary matrix $\textbf{U}$ where each column is made of the eigenstate. i.e.
$$
\textbf{U}^{\dagger}\textbf{H}\textbf{U}=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
E_{1} &  & 0\\
 & ...\\
0 &  & E_{N}
\end{array}\right)
$$
where $\textbf{U}$ is,
$$
\textbf{U}=
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\psi_{11} & \psi_{12} & \psi_{13} & ...\\
\psi_{21} & \psi_{22} & \psi_{23}\\
\psi_{31} & \psi_{32} & \psi_{33}\\
... &  &  & ...
\end{array}\right)
$$
and each column of the unitary matrix is the eigenvector of the Hamiltonian.
$$
\left|\psi_{j}\right\rangle=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\psi_{1j}\\
\psi_{2j}\\
\psi_{3j}\\
...
\end{array}\right)
$$ Now consider a new Hamiltonian $\textbf{H}^{'}$ that can be diagonalized using a paraunitary matrix $\textbf{P}$ instead of the unitary matrix $\textbf{P}$.
$$
\textbf{P}^{\dagger}\textbf{H}^{'}\textbf{P}=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
E_{1} &  & 0\\
 & ...\\
0 &  & E_{2N}
\end{array}\right)
$$
where $\textbf{P}$ satisfying following relations:
$$
\textbf{P}\sigma_3\textbf{P}^{\dagger}=\textbf{P}^{\dagger}\sigma_3\textbf{P}=\sigma_3
$$
with $\sigma_3\equiv diag\left(1,1,1,...,-1-1-1\right)$.
If my understanding is correct, one example of such Hamiltonian is the [quadratic Bogoliubov bosonic Hamiltonian](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0378437178901607?via%3Dihub).

My question is, does the formalism about the regular unitary matrices in matrix representation also work for the paraunitary matrix case? In other words, the column components of $\textbf{P}$ are the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian $\textbf{H}^{'}$? If the answer is no, how am I supposed to define eigenvectors in matrix representation?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think what you call paraunitary is what some other people call complex symplectic.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with your "para-unitary" scheme. As  I understand it, the  diagonalization of the general bosonic hamiltonian via Bogoliubov transformations relies on *Williamson's theorem* and the associated *symplectic spectrum* of the  matrix.  A link to the basic linear algebra is [here](http://people.physics.illinois.edu/stone/bose_bogoliubov.pdf).